# Upper right Bootstrap panel has top offset when using many columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently trying to build a grid, which shows many panels (in my case they are search results) in many columns over many rows.

However, the most upper right panel does have an offset as you can see in the image below.

[image]

My code looks like the following, you can [view and edit it directly on bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/4AzINnvVVv).

```
<div class="row">´
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... more columns ... -->
</div>
```

In Chrome Canary it is fine after resizing the window. In IE11 the problem is always visible.

What's the reason and how could I fix it?

Comment: Just remove that extra `´` character in your markup

Comment: No way.... 2 hours of searching just because Eclipse has no support for 200dpi and my bad eyes :( Thanks!